# Installation of MySQL 5.7 on Debian 8 fails

Tags: debian, mysql

I have a problem installing MySQL 5.7.

I downloaded the file [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) with Windows and put it with ftp in the temp directory of my server, because `wget` always timed out.

Then I executed `sudo dpkg -i /tmp/mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb`.

I get `Setting up mysql-apt-config (0.7.3-1) ...`, but nothing else happens after that. I tried it already several times.

There are no other mysql packages installed on my server.

Are there any other ways to install MySQL 5.7? Everything I found on Google couldn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my server has some problems with its internet connection. All connections to the MySQL repo do fail (that is a bit strange, because the connection to the official debian repository is working), so I downloaded the whole installation files (not the APT Repository) manually (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) with a Windows computer and put them with FTP on the server. With some dependencie errors I finally got MySQL 5.7 installed.

Edit: Later I found out that my server had no IPv4 address...

Answer (score 1):

You are much better off using MySQL's apt repo. Here is a link to the download and there are instructions on setting it up on the page: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

After that you can just run `apt-get update && apt-get install mysql-server` and be good to go.

Comment: I have downloaded it there and followed the instructions. It does not work! It fails while setting up

Answer (score 1):

You have already added the mysql repository to your `sources.list` (by runing `dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb`) , Just update and install it :

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

**Edit**

You can add manually the MySQL APT repository:

download the GPG key to your APT keyring directly using the apt-key utility:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5072E1F5
```

Edit (create) the file named `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list`, and put
in the following format:

```
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian jessie mysql-5.7
```

Update and install it:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: No, nothing gets added by running that command, because nothing happens after `Setting up ...`. It is maybe an infinite loop? Now I added manually the line `deb http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/ mysql main` in my `sources.list`, but now I get that error: http://pastebin.com/eG0YuWwQ